# Image not loading html java

Tags: java, html, servlets

I have the below html code that displays an image when a user selects my url/location. If US, US image loads, and if Japan, japan image loads.

```
<body>
<div class="bodyStyle" style="width: 100%; height: 680px">      
    <div align="center">
        <div class="mainHeader" style="background-color: smokewhite; height: 300px; margin: 10px; margin-left: 15px; width: 480px;">
          <div class=“showUSImage” style="display: none"> 
          <img src=“@RESORT@“ height="250px" width="250px">
          </div>
          <div class=“showJapanImage” style="display: none">              
          <img src="@ RESORT@" height="150px"width="150px">
          </div>    
          <div class="textSize" style="font-size:50;font-family:Times New Roman;”><p><b>Welcome to our resort homes</b></p></div>           
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Java code (I am only pasting the method I am using to generate the Html response). I don't see issues loading the file, but the image is not getting displayed. I only see the text Welcome to our resort homes-

```
private void generateHTMLResponse(ServletRequest request,String fileName,boolean isUs){
   FileReader reader = null;
   String defaultHTML = IOUtils.toString(reader);           
   String usImage = “http://myresortHomes/” + "images/US.png";
   String japanImage = “http://myresortHomes/” + "images/Japan.png";
   final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
   String header = httpRequest.getHeader(“Country”);
   if(isUs) {               
      defaultHTML = defaultHTML.replaceAll("RESORT", usImage);              
      HTML_RESPONSE = defaultHTML.getBytes();
   }
   else {   
      defaultHTML = defaultHTML.replaceAll("RESORT", japanImage);               
      HTML_RESPONSE = defaultHTML.getBytes();
   }
}
```

I am pretty sure I have the html page wrong. I have no experience in html, so request you please help.

Comment: Okay why would you down-vote and vote to close without responding to my post? This is just really bad.

Comment: Get some experience in HTML and fast. I won't vote to close, but it's still unclear what's happening and what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: If your attitude is that, I'll vote to close too. Explain what's happening and what you expect to happen. The better your question, the more likely you'll get an answer. But at least your HTML has one image tag too much (and they're named stupidly).

Comment: You don't see anything: `style="display: none"`. Where is the javascript code which change the visibility?

Comment: @Aubin - I am honestly not sure how to include javascript in html. I don't need the code here, but can you atleast point me to any old post where I can get some help. I have never done html in my life, and this is a sample I got by looking at other html pages in my application. I have no way of knowing if its right, so needed your advise there.

Comment: *" I have no way of knowing if its right"*  Yes you do.  Learn how HTML works.  It is a prerequisite to making this work.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted can't possibly generate anything, because you're starting with `null`, but let's assume you've modified it to simplify it.

Also, your code is not thread-safe. Servlets should be thread-safe, so you should return the HTML_RESPONSE instead of using a global variable (which should not be named in ALL CAPS, by the way, as it's a *variable* - all caps are only for *constants*). Global variables are bad!

But the basic problem here is you seem to be using/inventing a "template language" in which @ symbols are used to delineate what is to be replaced - which is good, you should use a proper template language - but then instead of using an actual template engine, you've tried to implement it yourself, but you've implemented it wrongly.

**Best solution:** Use a real template engine, such as JSP, or one of the numerous other ones.

**Quick solution:** Remove the space after the third @ symbol, then change your code to `defaultHTML.replaceAll("@RESORT@", usImage)`. Also, fix the thread-safety issue (see above). Also, fix the `display:none` issue by removing the `style=display:none`.